# Rows in wrong order for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

My application uploads records one at a time and stores them in the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database at about 5Hz, using 10 tables for 10 different types of data. Up to about 1800 records, there are no issues however for some reason at around this point all the tables start to skip records in the order they are stored, and these appear later on in the database out of sequence. I have confirmed they are definitely being uploaded (over a wireless connection) in the correct order. I need to have row IDs in the correct chronological sequence.

So far I have tried an ID column which is incremented by a python server script using pyodbc for every new record per table when the record is stored. Also I have tried the auto-increment feature when creating the table from LabVIEW. Both approaches have the same issue outlined above.

I am not a database expert so any advice would be welcome. Can anyone explain what is happening here? If SQL Server won't let me insert records in the order they are uploaded for some reason, maybe I can order the records by timestamp and then add IDs according to their row number after the tables are populated. Any guidance on how to resolve this would be very welcome.

In answer to ninesided's questions, I am uploading the records one at a time, and I know they are in the wrong order due to database insertion because the records have been timestamped but are put into the database out of order. (This is confirmed by checking transmission logs which show they are uploaded in the correct sequence.)

Tim, I am concerned that to use ORDER BY this limits the size of my database to 8060 bytes according to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188723%28v=sql.105%29.aspx. Also, would this actually change the sequence of rows in the database table itself, or is it just a selection tool?

*EDIT Thanks for the insight and understanding from you all. I have resolved the issue by just using ORDER BY ID whenever accessing the data. Simpler than I thought it would be!

Comment: A table has no inherent order, you need to apply an `ORDER BY`. Only the optimizer decides in which order the rows are returned if you omit the `ORDER BY`, so you cannot rely on it.

Comment: Can you enlighten us as to how you are "uploading" the records? Are you inserting them one at a time, or in a batches? Also, what makes you believe they are in the wrong order in the database?

Comment: What do you use to track this _sequence_ that you speak of? An incrementing integer? If so, instead of using an incrementing column, could you not just update the ID column with the value from the source? I.e. `Target.Id 1 = Source.Id 1`. Also please answer comments by using a comment and edit question when it's needs to be clarified :)

Comment: Apologies Mackan. The sequence is currently an auto-incremented ID. The source is another system connected wirelessly so I can't do that, unless you mean updating the ID column with the row number which the database shows... I would like to know how to do this.

Comment: Whilst, of course, rows must be being stored, physically, in some order, there's no way to control that process. There are some constructs which allow you to apply some logical ordering (clustered index) but that's only defined/documented to assist with optimizing data access (especially useful for range queries). When it comes to the order in which *results* are returned to you/your application the *only* defined/documented way to do that is to apply an `ORDER BY` on that query. For any query without an `ORDER BY`, you're telling the server - any order, whatever works well for you.

Comment: To clarify, once the records have been stored there is absolutely no way whatsoever to rearrange them physically?

Comment: The columns that you specify in your Order By clause cannot exceed 8060 bytes in total. This limit has nothing to do with the size of your database, number of rows or columns in your table. For example if you had a table with 10 columns that were all `varchar(2000)`, then you could specify and order based on up to 4 of the cols. But you could return all 10 columns in a SELECT statement.

Comment: Apart from if your having performance problems, you really shouldn't care about how records are physically stored. You would be better of spending time specifying some good indexes.

Comment: There are some (administrative) ways to change the physical storage order but, as I hope is already clear from the comments, the physical storage order is not a guarantee on the order in which results are returned - so it wouldn't "solve" your problem to perform those administrative activities.

Comment: Many thanks. Glad to know about the 8060 byte limitation being only for column specifications. I see that if using ORDER BY it doesn't really matter about how the data is physically stored. I'm a bit surprised at no physical rearrangement being supported for something as basic as making sure the records are in the right chronological order (which seems a bit sloppy), but the user won't see any difference I suppose.

Comment: Although SQL is a bit sloppy with it in places, it's inspired by "relational theory" and what we're working with are (meant to be) sets - and sets have no order. The two sets `{a,b}` and `{b,a}` are exactly the same set. And so that's why physical ordering is hidden away, as much as possible.